# Change default directory in Snowpack Vue app

Tags: vue.js, snowpack

I want to use [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/) for my Vue 3 app. Currently, I've initialized the Vue 3 app using the following command:

```
npx create-snowpack-app my-app --template @snowpack/app-template-vue
```

By default, Snowpack creates a directory structure like this:

```
public/
src/
  App.vue
  index.js
package.json
README.md
snowpack.config.js
```

I need to restructure things slightly. The reason why is I'm moving an existing app to Snowpack. My challenge is I need to move to a structure like this:

```
public/
pages/
  App.vue
index.js
package.json
README.md
snowpack.config.js
```

In short: 1) rename `src` to `pages` and 2) move `index.js` up to the same level as `package.json`. When I make this change, Snowpack throws a warning that says "mounted directory does not exist". It prints out the files it's looking for, which, Snowpack is clearly still looking in the `src` directory. My thinking was to review the `snowpack.config.js` file.

I looked at the [`mount` property](https://www.snowpack.dev/reference/configuration#mount) in the `snowpack.config.js` file. I changed `mount.src.url` to `/pages`. However, that didn't work. I also tried changing the property to just `/`, which also didn't work.

What do I need to change to tell Snowpack to look in the current directory instead of the `src` directory for the `index.js` file?

Comment: That one does not work ? `mount: { url: '/pages' }`

Comment: @kissu - No. I suspect it has to do with the fact that I moved `index.js` up one directory. I believe I need to update some config to say where `index.js` is located. However, I can't figure out which config option is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That directory layout is possible with a `mount` config that specifies `.` as the mount point:

```js
// snowpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  mount: {
    '.': {url: '/dist'}
  },
}
```

Then the root index could import the SFC from `<projectRoot>/pages/`:

```js
// <projectRoot>/index.js
import App from './pages/App.vue'
...
```